# add element to a combo box created with zend_form with element from ajax response

Tags: zend-framework, jquery, combobox

how can i fill a combo box with element from ajax response
ps: the combo box is created with Zend_form

My form

```
<?php

class Application_Form_SearchProduct extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
      $this->setName("SearchProduct");

      $a=new Application_Model_Class_Categories();
      $this->setMethod('post');  


      /* Combo box Category*/
        $this->addElement('Select', 'Category',array(
         'label'      => 'Category:',
         'AutoComplete'=> true, 

          'MultiOptions'   => $a->GetCategories(),
         'required' => true )); 


                 /* Combo box SubCategory*/

        $this->addElement('Select', 'SubCategory',array(
         'label'      => 'Sub Category:',
         'AutoComplete'=> true, 


         'required' => true )); 

      $this->addElement('submit', 'Search', array(
            'required' => false,
            'ignore'   => true,
            'label'    => 'Search',
        ));  }   }
?>
```

the js script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //for send data i'll use jquery library

    $(document).ready( function(){
            $('#Category').change(function()
               {

                   var message=$('#Category option:selected').text();
                  if (message != '') {

                      //run ajax

                     $.ajax({
type: "GET", // envoi des données en POST
url: 'http://localhost/EverTags1/Authentification1/public/Product', 

    //baseurl+"/Product/index", 

data:  {'message' : message},

cache: false,
success:  function (respond) {
                               //put respond in class show-msg


                                     //$("#menuLeft").html(respond);  
                                    $("#SubCategory").add(respond);                 

 }
})
 ; }});});
   </script>
```

my action

```
  public function indexAction()
    {

       $form = new Application_Form_SearchProduct(); 

       $this->view->form = $form;
       $b=new Application_Model_Class_SubCategories();
       $message = $_GET['message'];
       $result = $b->GetSubCategories($message );
       echo($result[0]) ;

    }
```

$result[0] contains the folowing string Women's Clothing

and i have another problem when i choose the element from the first combo box the page autoduplicates and i can't find the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution of my problem

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //for send data i'll use jquery library

    $(document).ready( function(){
            $('#Category').change(function()
               {

                  var message=$('#Category option:selected').text();
                  if (message != '') {
$.ajax({
type: "GET", // envoi des données en POST
dataType : 'json',
url:  //baseurl+"Product/index",
    'http://localhost/EverTags1/Authentification1/public/Product/index', 
async: false,  
data:{"message" : message}, 
success:  
    function (respond) {

   var json=JSON.stringify(respond);
   var  objet = eval('(' + json + ')');

      e=objet.length;

      var str = "";

    for ( var count = 0 ; count < e; count++ ) { 


        str += "<option value='" + count + "'>" + objet[count].name+ "</option>"
    } 

     $("#SubCategory").empty().append(""+str);
 }

}
); 

}});});
   </script>
```

the action:

```
public function indexAction()
    {


         $form = new Application_Form_SearchProduct(); 
         $this->view->form = $form;


if($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
      $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
      $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
           $message = $_GET['message'];

         $soap_client = new nusoap_client('http://127.0.0.1/evertags/GetCategorySubCategories/servSubCategories.php?wsdl','true');
         $proxy = $soap_client->getProxy();
         $result= $proxy->ReturnSubCategoriesNames($message);

          echo $result;



}
```

I hope it will help other people

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
echo($result[0])
```

try:

```
$this->view->result = $result[0];
```

and change your success function to:

```
success: function(data.result) {
    $("#SubCategory").add(data.result);
}
```

Comment: Your data.result is the expected value ?

Comment: Try jQuery("#SubCategory").empty().append("<option value='" + data.result + "'>" + data.result + "</option>");

Comment: first thank you for helping me. the combobox is filled with undefined. i think the problem is in the action it return the html code of the page i try with dataType: 'json', and i add  public function init()
    {
         $contextSwitch = $this->_helper->getHelper('contextSwitch');
        $contextSwitch->addActionContext('index','json')
                    ->initContext();
    }    but i have the alert [object Object] i don't know how to recover the data from the action so I can use them in the script